# Как сделать,чтобы программа закрывалась при отсутствии интернет-подключения?

Tags: c++, windows

Как сделать,чтобы программа закрывалась при отсутствии интернет-подключения?Примеров к сожалению не нашёл.

Comment: Под какую ос Вам нужно?

Comment: @SKIP Windows       .

Comment: Фреймворк qt подойдет?

Comment: @SKIP Пример можно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю нужно Вам нужно поучиться искать материал и пользоваться поисковиком.

[Пример 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075201/checking-internet-connection-in-c-using-internetcheckconnection)

[Пример 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778404/programmatically-check-whether-my-machine-has-internet-access-or-not)

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcheckconnectiona)

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <wininet.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")
void check() {

    if (!InternetCheckConnection("http://www.google.com", FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0))
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Нужно добавить функцию `check()` в [thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

P.S: если результат проверки слишком критичен и не может содержать не в коем случае ошибку, сверять интернет нужно по нескольким сайтам.